# Forgot password not working

Tags: php, database, email, forgot-password

I have some code for the case when user forgot their password but its not working. When users proceed, messages is not send to their email. What is wrong?

This is code in PHP

```
require_once 'includes/definitions.php';
require_once FUNCS_DIR . 'core.functions.php';

$pid = 13;

$template->assign(PAGE_TITLE, $langs[47]);
$template->assign(PAGE_ID, $pid);

/* Rendering template */

$errors = array();
$step = 1;

$reset_code = null;

if(empty($_POST) == false) {

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

        $email = $_POST['email';

        if (email_exists($email) == false)
            $errors[] = $langs[264];

        if (empty($errors)) {

            $reset_code = md5($_POST['email'] + microtime());

            update_email_code($email, $reset_code);

            $data['reset_link'] = get_setting('base_url') . 'forgot_password?reset_code=' . $reset_code;

            send_email_template('forgot_password.tpl', $data, $email, get_setting('site_name') . ' - Password Reset');
        }

    }else{

        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password_repeat = $_POST['password_repeat'];
        $reset_code = $_POST['reset_code'];

        $member_data = get_member_email_code($reset_code);

        $step = 2;

        if($member_data == false)
            $errors[] = $langs[265];

        if($password != $password_repeat)
            $errors[] = $langs[266];

        if(strlen($password) < get_setting('min_pass_length'))
            $errors[] = $langs[267];

        if(!preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $password))
            $errors[] = $langs[268];

        if (!preg_match('#[0-9]#', $password))
            $errors[] = $langs[269];

        if(empty($errors)){

            $password_hash = hash('sha256', $password);

            if(update_password($member_data['members_id'], $password_hash)){
                redirect('login?pr=true');
            }else{
                $errors[] = $langs[270];
            }

        }

    }

}

if(empty($_GET) == false){

    $reset_code = $_GET['reset_code'];
    $member_data = get_member_email_code($reset_code);

    if(empty($reset_code)){
        $errors[] = $langs[271];
    }else if($member_data == false){
        $errors[] = $langs[272];
    }

    if(empty($errors)){

        $step = 2;

    }

}

$template->assign('reset_code', $reset_code);

$template->assign('errors', $errors);
$template->assign('step', $step);

$template->display($current_template . 'forgot_password.tpl');
```

Comment: Where is the actual `mail()` call to send the email?

Comment: You dropped something here: `$email = $_POST['email';`

Comment: Also where is the `send_mail_template()` function?

Answer (score 0):

When your script doesn't work. Look in error logs first. In this case, you should see a syntax error on this line:

```
$email = $_POST['email';
```

Replace it with:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Comment: yes there was a mistake on copy paste. when you put email for reset passord shown this message : We have sent an email asking you to reset your password. Please check your spam folder. but messages doesnt go to email i entered and in error log doesnt show enything